# Cocos2d handwriting recognition....HOW...?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ocr

i am trying to make a game in which i am tying to implement handwriting recognition,

what i exactly want is that when the user slides his finger on the screen a line should be created wherever he slides the finger and when he lifts his finger i want to check that the image which he created matches to any alphabet(a,b,c...z)and if yes then to which alphabet.

i tried drawing the lines using CGSprites but it is leading to a huge fps drop and later crashing of the app if the user keeps sliding his finger,but i have no idea how to recognize it.

can anyone please till me if this is anyway possible,if yes can you please provide me with some idea of how to approach this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Heh...that's tricky.  You are in for some work.  On the bright side, are you thinking ScribbleNaughts?  I'd buy that :)  Wouldn't want to code it though lol.  My best guess is it would involve a lot of math.  Counting corners, counting curves.  Checking what order a curve and an angle connect in, and what angle (vector?) the corner is going...etc.

Comment: First, the crash - have you tested to see how many sprites you are drawing?  They're probably exponentially growing as you slide you finger!  Second - I did some work into basic mouse (or mouse like motion) gesture/pattern recognition a few years ago, got some basic stuff working using neural nets but it was a real world of hurt - if I was in your position I'd look for a good established library or look for a new project - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For the line drawing I would suggest using basic OpenGL calls to draw the line. Store the points however you want with every touch moved event and then in the draw function for your node you should setup OpenGL state to meet your line drawing needs...

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glLineWidth(2.5f);
```

then iterate over your list of points and use something like

```
ccDrawLine(pA, pB);
```

to draw the line between those points.

As for using that data to detect letters, that's a very tricky problem. You might want to look for libraries to do that for you. If you're dead set on doing it yourself, then you should start with looking for research papers on handwriting recognition.

Answer (score 1):

For drawing the line you can also use CCRibbon
define a CCRibbon and keep a reference to it
you should use a proper image for ribbon

CCRibbon *line = [CCRibbon ribbonWithWidth: image: length: color: fade:];

then in  your touch handler when touch moves add new points to CCRibbon

[line addPointAt: width:];

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three different solutions.

1. Use an existing library. Maybe you will not find one written in Objective-C, but using any C or C++-Library should also be easy. For example you could use [AMELiA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amelibraries/) or [Lipi Toolkit](http://lipitk.sourceforge.net/index.htm).
2. Write a [Custom Gesture Recognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2) for the different letters
3. Implement it yourself. You could use neural networks or support vector machines. You can train them with some of the free datasets on the net. Markov Models are also commonly used to solve this problem. However unless you want to learn a lot of theory and have a good knowledge of mathematics I would not recommend this approach.